# I always get this error as program output:ValueError: factorial() not defined for negative values. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to solve a combination problem in python. In stdin I have to insert n and M on the same line(integer type) and on the output I have to get the value of k.
I also have some restrictions: `k` <= `N`. `k` is an integer, too

```
import math

n = 0
M = 0
n, M = raw_input().split()
n = int(n)
M = int(M)
k = n
C = 1
ok = 0

while True:
    C = math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))
    k = k + 1
    if C <= M:
        ok = 1
    if C > M:
        break
if ok == 0:
    print("0")
else:
    print(int(k))
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Combinari.py", line 13, in <module>
    C = math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial(n - k))
ValueError: factorial() not defined for negative values
```

Comment: Probably because `n - k` is a negative value in the `math.factorial(n - k)` call. Perhaps you need to `break` when `k > n` since your loop changes the value of `k` each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Since `k = n` in the beginning, and for each iteration `k = k + 1` you will always have the error.
I think you should do `k = k - 1` if you are looking for the value of `k`